Given a convex set $A$ in $R^n$, when is Fr $A$ convex?
I am self-studying topology using Viro et al.'s Elementary Topology Problem Textbook. The question above occurs early in the text, and though I have a solution, it feels a little ugly to me, and I would appreciate knowing if it can be made more elegant.
Here's what I have:
Fr $A$ is convex if Fr $A$ is contained in an $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  If $A$ is bounded and not contained in any $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then Fr $A$ is not convex.
For the first claim, let Fr $A$ be contained in an $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $x, y \in$ Fr $A$, $z \in [x,y]$.  Since Fr $A$ = Cl $A \setminus$ Int $A$, $x,y \in $ Cl $A$.  We already know that if $A$ is convex, Cl $A$ is convex as well.  So $z \in$  Cl $A$.  Now let $U$ be a neighborhood of $z$.  Then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(z) \subseteq U$, where $B_\epsilon(z)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $z$.  Since $B_\epsilon(z)$ is an $n$-dimensional set while Fr $A$ is contained in an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace, we cannot have $B_\epsilon(z) \subseteq Fr A$.  Thus $U \not \subseteq$ Fr $A$, which means $z \notin$ Int $A$.  So $z \in$ Fr $A = $ Cl $A \setminus$ Int $A$, which means that Fr $A$ is convex.
For the second claim, assume that $A$ is bounded and not contained in an $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $A$ contains an open ball; let $B_\epsilon(z)$ be such a ball, where $\epsilon > 0$ and $z$ is the ball's center.  Since $z \in B_\epsilon(z)$ and $B_\epsilon(z)$ is open, $z \in$ Int $A$.
Since $A$ is bounded, Cl $A$ is bounded, and certainly $z \in$ Cl $A$. Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Then $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n|x = z + \lambda u; \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a line passing through (z).  Since Cl $A$ is bounded, we can define $\lambda_x = \sup\{\lambda > 0|z + \lambda u \in A\}$.  By the definition of $\sup$, for any $\delta > 0$ we can find $\epsilon_0$ with $0 \leq \epsilon_0 < \delta$ such that $z + (\lambda - \epsilon_0)u \in A$ and $\epsilon_1$ with $0 \leq \epsilon_1 < \delta$ such that $z + (\lambda + \epsilon_1)u \notin A$.  So $z + \lambda_xu \in$ Cl $A$ and $z + \lambda_xu \notin$ Int $A$.  Thus $z + \lambda_x u \in$ Fr $A$. Let $x = z + \lambda_x u$.  Similarly, define $\lambda_y = \sup\{\lambda < 0|z + \lambda u \in A\}$.  Setting $y = z + \lambda_yu$, we have $y \in$ Fr $A$ as well.  Now, $z \in [x,y]$, but since $z \in$ Int $A$, $z \notin$ Fr $A$.  So Fr $A$ is not convex.
As I say, I do not believe my reasoning is wrong, so far as it goes; I just worry that I haven't covered all the bases.  It would feel better to me if, for example, the boundedness requirement didn't put in an appearance, or if I could show that Fr $A$ is convex if and only if Fr $A$ is contained in an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but somehow something so general eludes me.  Any thoughts or insight would be appreciated.

What does $\operatorname{Fr} A$ mean? I've never seen this notation.

It's the text's notation for the boundary of a set.  I believe other sources might use $\partial A$.

Presumably "Fr" stands for "frontier". As a bit of a nitpick, you shouldn't refer to the title in the body of your MSE questions: the body should be self-contained.

The cases you are missing include the half-spaces in $\Bbb{R}^n$. I don't think there are any others.

You said "the question above" and the only question above is the title. Having read your statements more carefully, I see that your first case does cover half-spaces, but you could answer the question in what I think is a more informative way: for convex $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$, $\mathrm{Fr},A$ is convex iff either $A$ is contained in a an $(n-1)$-dimensional affine subspace or $A$ is an affine half-space. (I deleted the bit about convex caps, that was wrong.)

@RobArthan I believe the half-spaces in $\mathbb{R}^b$
are covered by the first case, aren't they? That is, the frontier (or boundary, or what you will) of a half-space $H^n$
is a hyperplane, and so is contained in an $(n−1)$
-dimensional affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$
(and is therefore convex). Am I wrong about this? As for convex caps, those are what worry me. And as for your nitpick, I'm happy to fix whatever I did wrong, but I can't see where I mentioned my question's title in the body. Or are you referring to the title of the textbook?

Our edits to comments crossed in the post, but I think we should be in agreement now.

@RobArthan This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.
